# How do I create a table wth both plain and robust standard errors?

Tags: stata

I often see regression tables in publications where the plain standard errors are reported (in parentheses), together with the robust standard errors (in brackets) *below* the plain standard errors. The tables also include the accompanying asterisks beside the parentheses/brackets indicating statistical significance.

What is the most sensible way to create regression reports like these?

So far, I have been using the `estout` package in Stata. For a given model, I could have one column with the plain standard error and another with the robust one.

For example, using `estout`, I could do the following:

```
eststo: qui reg ROE duality
eststo: qui reg ROE duality, vce(cluster firm)

esttab b(%9.3fc) ///                     
       se(%9.3fc) ///
       star (* 0.5 ** 0.25)
```

The aforementioned code snippet produces:

```
--------------------------------------------
                (1)             (2)   
                ROE             ROE   
--------------------------------------------
duality       -8.090**        -8.090*   
              (6.585)         (7.067)   
--------------------------------------------
N               647             647   
--------------------------------------------
```

However, this table wastes column space as the point estimates of the two columns will be identical, with the only difference being the standard errors from the different variance-covariance estimators.

What I would much rather have is a table like the one below:

```
 ------------------------
                (1)      
                ROE      
-------------------------
duality       -8.090     
              (6.585)** 
              [7.067]*   
-------------------------
N               647      
-------------------------
```

Note that indication of statistical significance at 0.5 and 0.25 is for illustration here only and certainly does not reflect convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that appropriate indication of significance can be displayed for both the regular standard errors and the robust standard errors separately by including the robust p-values in the estimation set and then selecting them using the `pvalue()` suboption within `cells()`. Here is an example:

```
sysuse auto

regress price weight mpg
est sto m1
regress price weight mpg, vce(robust)
matrix table = r(table)
matrix r_se = table[2,1...]
matrix r_p = table[4,1...]
estadd matrix r_se: m1
estadd matrix r_p: m1

regress price weight mpg turn
est sto m2
regress price weight mpg turn, vce(robust)
matrix table = r(table)
matrix r_se = table[2,1...]
matrix r_p = table[4,1...]
estadd matrix r_se: m2
estadd matrix r_p: m2

esttab m1 m2, mtitle nonumber            ///
   cell(b(fmt(a3))                       ///
        se(par star)                     ///
        r_se(par([ ]) star pvalue(r_p))  ///
        )                                ///
    note(@starlegend)

--------------------------------------------
                       m1              m2   
                b/se/r_se       b/se/r_se   
--------------------------------------------
weight              1.747           3.524   
                  (0.641)**       (0.817)***
                  [0.778]*        [1.159]** 
mpg                -49.51          -72.87   
                  (86.16)         (81.30)   
                  [95.81]         [97.07]   
turn                               -395.2   
                                  (122.6)** 
                                  [177.4]*  
_cons              1946.1         12744.2   
                 (3597.0)        (4760.1)** 
                 [4213.8]        [6429.0]   
--------------------------------------------
N                      74              74   
--------------------------------------------
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to manually add the robust standard errors:

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear

quietly regress price weight mpg, vce(robust)
matrix regtab = r(table)
matrix regtab = regtab[2,1...]
matrix rbse = regtab

eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg

estadd matrix rbse = rbse
esttab, cells(b se rbse)

-------------------------
                      (1)
                    price
                b/se/rbse
-------------------------
weight           1.746559
                 .6413538
                  .777837
mpg             -49.51222
                 86.15604
                  95.8074
_cons            1946.069
                  3597.05
                 4213.793
-------------------------
N                      74
-------------------------
```

Formatting it to your specifications requires using the relevant options:

```
esttab , cells("b(fmt(a3) star)" "se(fmt(a2) par)" "rbse(fmt(a2) par([ ]))") ///
star(* 0.5 ** 0.25)  addnote("Robust SE in brackets" "* p<0.5, ** p<0.25") ///
nonumbers

---------------------------
                    price  
                b/se/rbse  
---------------------------
weight              1.747**
                   (0.64)  
                   [0.78]  
mpg                -49.51  
                   (86.2)  
                   [95.8]  
_cons              1946.1  
                 (3597.0)  
                 [4213.8]  
---------------------------
N                      74  
---------------------------
Robust SE in brackets
* p<0.5, ** p<0.25
```

Comment: Thanks Pearly! This comes very close to what I have in mind, but is it possible to have the indication of significance at the SEs instead of the point estimate, since the SEs also determine the level of statistical significance?

Comment: I noticed that line 6 and 7 can be more concise by using `matrix rbse = regtab[2,1...]`, but I understand that the original code might be easier to decode for a newbie like me.

Comment: Yes, lines 6 and 7 can be merged to one line. Regarding the stars, you can have them where you like by changing the `star` option, i.e. `b(fmt(a3))` and `se(fmt(a2) par star)`.

Comment: I did try that, using `cells("b(fmt(a3))" "se(fmt(a2) star)" "rbse(fmt(a2) par([ ]) star)") star(* 0.05 ** 0.01) `, but the indication of significance seems to follow the one of the last ran regression. That is, I get 2 stars for both the plain SE and the robust SE, when it should have been 2 stars for the plain SE and 1 star for the robust SE.

Comment: I am not sure if you can bypass this issue. This is how `estout` is coded so i would suggest you to contact its author.