# Convert a multilevel output from xthtaylor to a matrix in Stata

Tags: matrix, stata

In Stata, after running the `xthtaylor` command, the command

```
matrix regtab = r(table)
```

yields an empty matrix. I think this is because of the multilevel of the output of this command [image]
Being new to Stata, I haven't found how to fix this. The purpose here is to extract the coeffecient and standard errors to add them to another output (as is done in the accepted solution of [How do I create a table wth both plain and robust standard errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816692/how-do-i-create-a-table-wth-both-plain-and-robust-standard-errors))

Comment: This is a forum for programmers, so as a programmer what is your strategy here? You could try cloning `xthtaylor` and modifying it,  or work with what it does leave behind, as shown by `ereturn list`.

Comment: Thanks! This helped, I just had to do `ereturn display`, which showed the results again and then `matrix tab = r(table)` worked to get the results in a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Nick's point: `matrix regtab = r(table)` gives you an empty matrix, because `xthtaylor` doesn't put anything into `r(table)`.

To see this run the following example:

```
clear all // empties r(table) and everything else
webuse psidextract
* the example regression from `help xthtaylor`
xthtaylor lwage wks south smsa ms exp exp2 occ ind union fem blk ed, endog(exp exp2 occ ind union ed) constant(fem blk ed)
```

`return list` doesn't have anything in `r(table)`, but `ereturn list` will show you that you have access to the coefficients through `e(b)` and the variance-covariance matrix through `e(V)`.

You can assign these to their own matrices as follows:

```
matrix betas = e(b)
matrix varcovar = e(V)
```

Then you can use matrix commands (see `help matrix`) to manipulate these matrices.

As you discovered, `ereturn display` creates `r(table)` which appears quite convenient for your use. It's worth taking a look at `help return` for more information about the differences between the contents of `return list` and `ereturn list`.